# Using ReaderWriterLockSlim for Opposite of readers-writer

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, concurrency, readerwriterlockslim

I need to allow multiple writers/single-reader at the same time.

I have found [ReaderWriterLockSlim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim(v=vs.110).aspx) class but I have a problem with the naming. I need to use EnterReadLock() for allowing writer to write and EnterWriteLock() for allowing reader to write, which can be a bit confusing for further use.

Does ReaderWriterLockSlim class have a wrapper class for my issue or can you suggest another solution.

Thanks!

Comment: *multiple writers/single-reader* you gotta stick with `lock`.

Comment: What resource are you protecting such that it's safe for there to be multiple writers? And if there's only a single reader, why do you need a lock at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use .Net 4.5 or later, I recommend using the [Task Parallel Library's](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. (You install the TPL via Nuget.)

See [here](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/11/async-producerconsumer-queue-using.html) and [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228601%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for sample code.

Alternatively, you could look in to using [`BlockingCollection`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), which is supported by .Net 4.0 or later.

Both these classes make it relatively easy to share a queue between multiple writers and a single reader.

Comment: It is important to note that even though each method of BlockingCollection is thread-safe, an operation with multiple calls to BlockingCollection will not be atomic, and thus the user still need to use an additional locking model or a different coding model to simulate an atomic operation when accessing multiple methods of the object. BTW, collections like BlockingCollection and ConcurrentDictionary has methods that work with check-then-perform model as in do something only if a condition is satisfied (atomic) to try to eliminate the issue I have just described.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? Altough i would suggest you to stick to regular naming convention, making it easier for futur update from another guy.

```
class MyReaderWriterLockSlim: ReaderWriterLockSlim
{
    new public void EnterWriteLock()
    { base.EnterReadLock(); }

    new public void EnterReadLock()
    { base.EnterWriteLock(); }

    new public void ExitReadLock()
    { base.ExitWriteLock(); }

    new public void ExitWriteLock()
    { base.ExitReadLock(); }
}

class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        MyReaderWriterLockSlim myLock=new MyReaderWriterLockSlim();
        myLock.EnterReadLock();
        try
        {
            //do stuff
        }
        finally 
        { myLock.ExitReadLock(); }
    }
}
```